# Непонятный отступ после закрытия Modal bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Внутри модального окна от bootstrap вставил ссылку ведущую на другое модальное окно bootstrap и повесил событие при открытии второго модального окна скрывать первое вот так:

```
    $('#myModal_forgot_pass').on('show.bs.modal ', function () {
    $('#myModal_login').modal('toggle');
})
```

все корректно работает,выплывает второе окошко, первое закрывается, однако после закрытия второго окошка появляется непонятный отступ справа, который не ловится в консольке. и при повторе операций открывания отступ увеличивается с каждым закрытием второго окошка. Может кто нибудь сталкивался?

Answer (score 2):

Пропиши для body в CSS 
`padding-right:0px !important;`
Мне помогло )